# change text of a UITableViewCell when tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to update a UITableViewCell when it is tapped for a little feedback like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:aPath.row] isEqualToString:@"AirPrint Order"]) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Generating Order Receipt";
        NSArray *nsa = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:nsa withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

This code seems to do nothing even though in the debugger it does make it inside my if statement but nothing is happening with the cell text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` it actually calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again and reloads the cell, removing the changes that you applied to it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. What I advise you to do is: update your data in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and read it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.